# something about #define syntax in C

Tags: c

could any one explain what does

`#define something (54)`

mean? Why 54 is inside a bracket?

Comment: I have no idea if there is any benefit to putting it in bracket. Usually, outside bracket is fine.

Comment: There are a great many "quality" filters that run magic tests on questions and answers to try to filter out obviously bad ones. Writing in all lower-case may trigger one of the tests. Writing with frequent short paragraphs may trigger one. Writing without punctuation may trigger one. All together, it might not look very high quality to the automated tools. (And thank [SO] team for them -- the average quality is **much** higher since they have been introduced.)

Comment: [Further information on the filters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Comment: @sarnold I guess my question is too short, and I really have nothing to add for this particular question, so I copied the error message itself.

Comment: maybe post where you found this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis in that case are ignored. It's the same as writing:

```
#define something 54
```

They just help you like in math such as:

```
#define something (54-2)/2
```

Is different from

```
#define someotherthing 54-2/2
```

Comment: How does `(54)` help in a mathematical formula?  Why not extend it and use `((((((((((54))))))))))`?

Comment: Ed S.  You can indeed say ((((54)))).  It is redundant but not illegal.

Comment: Exactly, they help you to group up operations, the last expression would have 53 as value, while the second expression would have 26 as value.

Comment: I know I know, I just meant in this specific case where we are dealing with `(54)`.  I was just being difficult, don't mind me....

Comment: If MISRA is in play, I think the parenthesis are need to adhere to the quality standards.

Answer (score 4):

`#define something (54)` tells the C pre-processor to replace any text matching "something" with "(54)" before the code is actually compiled.

The reason you will often see the use of `( )` around a `#define` is that in some cases it prevents the replaced text from having adverse or undefined behavior when the `#defined` text is replaced into a larger expression. Such adverse effect might be the changing of operator precedence etc..

Comment: But, *in this specific case*, what purpose could the parens possibly serve?

Comment: in this specific case, none at all.

Answer (score 4):

It is in general a good idea to put any #define statement inside parenthesis.  This is a good habit, and most daily programmers adhere to good habits.

For instance:

```
#define TWO_PLUS_ONE    2 + 1
```

if I use it like this:

```
3 * TWO_PLUS_ONE
```

I would expect to see the answer as 9, however due to operator precedence, the calculated answer would be 7.  There are dozens of corner cases you could find like this (see http://www.gimpel.com/html/bugs.htm).  This is why C++ programmers scream, "Macros are evil!".  But we are C programmers, we are elite, we ain't scared.

The same example:

```
#define TWO_PLUS_ONE    (2 + 1)
```

This will give the expected result in all situations.

Most programmers want their practices to apply in all situations, so it is easy to remember, easy to practice and easy to do.  So in the simple case of

```
#define SOMETHING    (54)
```

Just do it.  It is a good idea.  Learn to be part of the team, they are trying to help you.  BTW, next they will say, "it should really be (54u)"

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are superfluous.  I cannot imagine a scenario in which `(54)` would differ semantically from `54`.  Now, if I'm wrong... show me; I'll have learned something new.

Comment: @sarnold... ok well now you're just being silly :D  How about this; show my a case which can actually compile (that uses the example as given, not a theoretical one in which `(foo)` is a type).

Comment: Okay, it is a bit silly, but the parens _would_ force a compile error: `25(54)` isn't valid for anything, but `2554` _is_...

Comment: @sarnold: Ho exactly can you force 2554 though a define?  25FOO is not going to have FOO be substituted because it is not a stand alone token.

Comment: @sarnold: Yeah that doesn't work, the whole thing will be interpreted as a token.

Comment: @SethRobertson: D'oh. Consider then `int foo = 25 something`.

Comment: hrm, I must be confusing my languages again. I thought C was friendly about spaces in numbers....

Comment: @sarnold: Nope, though sometimes I wish it were so I could write things like `int one_million = 1 000 000;` :D

Comment: The difference is for other macros like `#define bla(X) 0x ## X`, here `bla(something)` is a syntax error whereas `bla(54)` works and results in the token `0x54`.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use this

```
#define SOMETHING    (54)
```

instead of this

```
const int SOMETHING = 54;
```

I'm not sure what the answer to that is -- I think that this kind of use of `#define` may be somewhat archaic.  That said, **the use of the parentheses is nice, because it makes the two types of declarations behave in basically the same way**.  So now if you want to tweak the value...

```
#define SOMETHING (54+1)
```

or

```
const int SOMETHING = 54+1;
```

...they are still generally equivalent as "manifest constants".  Without the parentheses, they would not be equivalent because the `#define` is applied using simple substitution *before* the expression is evaluated.

So if the `#define` value is applied like so...

```
int a = 2*SOMETHING;
```

...you would get different results depending on whether or not the parentheses were used in the declaration:

```
int a = 2*54+1; // no parentheses -- answer is 109
int a = 2*(54+1); // parentheses -- answer is 110
```

Of course as long as the assigned value is a simple constant, as in your example, the presence of the parentheses makes no difference to the compiler.  **It is only for the benefit of the humans who are writing this code or who might modify this code in the future.**  By consistently applying this form of declaration, the author is attempting to reduce the occurrence of human error.

Answer (score 0):

"()" are parenthesis and not [brackets].  It is essentially a no-op.  Any time where 54 would be valid, (54) would be valid, just like (50+4) would be valid, or (27*2) or any other expression.

Perhaps you can give us more information about this "quality standards" error you are seeing?  Perhaps someone doesn't like the parens since they are unnecessary.

Comment: The quality issue is that you didn't provide enough information about the problem.  Why are you concerned about this?  What have you done to try and answer your question yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was written this way to make future changes easy; consider changing `54` to `1024*54` or `1024+54` -- with the parens, the change can be made directly without much further thought. If the change is made without the parens, then the precedence of operator evaluation matters *everywhere that `something` is used in the program*.